# Is there jbossconf like folder in Tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to migrate a web app from Jboss to Tomcat server. The webapp is dependent on the spring container and nothing else. In the context config file, I am referring to some of the property files as follows:

```
<entry key="passwordFile" value="jbossconf:passwords.xml"/>
```

Here the jbossconf refers to the configuration folder present in **$jboss_home/server/conf** folder.

When I am trying to move this web app to Tomcat, I need to use

```
<entry key="passwordFile" value="classpath:passwords.xml"/>
```

Is there any way to define a variable in tomcat like "tomcatconf" and make tomcat look for the configuration files inside this folder. Something like

```
<entry key="passwordFile" value="tomcatconf:passwords.xml"/>
```

The reason I am trying to do so is to avoid the mixing up of configuration files and the class files inside the same directory in my web app. If i put the configuration files inside classpath, then all the class files and the config files will be placed under **WEB-INF/classes** which I feel is not a good practice.

Alternate approach/suggestions for implementing this is most welcome.

Thanks,
Vishwa

Answer (score 0):

If the tomcat isn't on the same machine you can use an environment variable to define the root of configurations directory, so you can migrate the application without any change in code